# Mux segmented mpegts audio and video to single clip with error correction

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I have a recording as a collection of files in mpegts format, like

```
audio: a-1.ts, a-2.ts, a-3.ts, a-4.ts 
video: v-1.ts, v-2.ts, v-3.ts
```

I need to make a single video clip in mp4 or mkv format.

However, there are two problems:

1. audio and video segments have different duration each, number of audio segments is different from number of video segments. Total duration of audio and video matches. Hence I can not concat pairwise audio video segments using mpeg and merge them afterwards, I get sync issues increasing progressively
2. few segments are corrupt or missing. So if I concat audio and video streams separately using ffmpeg I get streams of different lengths. When I merge these streams using ffmpeg I have correct a/v synchronization until time when first missing packet is encountered.

It's OK if video freezes for a while or there is silence for a while as long as most of the video is in sync with audio.

I've checked with tsduck and PCR seems to be present in all audio and video segments yet I could not find a way to merge streams using mpegTS PCR as sync reference. Please advise how can I achieve this.

Comment: Do these segments have absolute timestamps?

Comment: Probably. Mpeg TS packets have PCR (Program Clock Reference) value, a long number which is there to sync clocks between sender and receiver (think satellite) and to sync video to audio. Yet I'm unable to leverage this info

Comment: How are you concating - commands and steps?

Comment: `
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i a_list.txt -c copy a.ts
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i v_list.txt -c copy v.ts
ffmpeg -i a.ts -i v.ts -c copy av.mp4
`